# Disable specific cart item quantity fields based on WooCommerce product category

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, product, cart

In woocommerce I am using [Hide “remove item” from cart for WooCommerce product category](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54033207/hide-remove-item-from-cart-for-woocommerce-product-category/54036824#54036824) answer code and I  would like to disable the cart quantity field too, avoiding customer to change the item quantity to zero.

Is that possible? Any track on this will be appreciated.

Comment: Just to clarify, it is located in the section when you view your cart page of woocommerce. From there you can reduce or gain quantity of the item. 
I was wondering if this can be disabled?
I was thinking if the delete button can be disabled that this can be as well???

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The following code will remove the "quantity field" from cart for items from a specific product category (that you will define in the 2nd function):

```
// Custom conditional function that handle parent product categories too
function has_product_categories( $categories, $product_id = 0 ) {
    $parent_term_ids = $categories_ids = array(); // Initializing
    $taxonomy        = 'product_cat';
    $product_id      = $product_id == 0 ? get_the_id() : $product_id;

    if( is_string( $categories ) ) {
        $categories = (array) $categories; // Convert string to array
    }

    // Convert categories term names and slugs to categories term ids
    foreach ( $categories as $category ){
        $result = (array) term_exists( $category, $taxonomy );
        if ( ! empty( $result ) ) {
            $categories_ids[] = reset($result);
        }
    }

    // Loop through the current product category terms to get only parent main category term
    foreach( get_the_terms( $product_id, $taxonomy ) as $term ){
        if( $term->parent > 0 ){
            $parent_term_ids[] = $term->parent; // Set the parent product category
            $parent_term_ids[] = $term->term_id; // (and the child)
        } else {
            $parent_term_ids[] = $term->term_id; // It is the Main category term and we set it.
        }
    }
    return array_intersect( $categories_ids, array_unique($parent_term_ids) ) ? true : false;
}

add_filter( 'woocommerce_quantity_input_args', 'hide_cart_quantity_input_field', 20, 2 );
function hide_cart_quantity_input_field( $args, $product ) {
    // HERE your specific products categories
    $categories = array( 'clothing' );

    // Handling product variation
    $product_id = $product->is_type('variation') ? $product->get_parent_id() : $product->get_id();

    // Only on cart page for a specific product category
    if( is_cart() && has_product_categories( $product_id, $categories ) ){
        $input_value = $args['input_value'];
        $args['min_value'] = $args['max_value'] = $input_value;
    }
    return $args;
}
```

Code goes in function.php file of your active child theme (or active theme). Tested and works.

> **Note:** If you are using also your other answer code, the first function is already defined and doesn"t have to be twice on your function php file…